# Como acceder a un objeto en un JSON para luego acceder a un campo en uno de sus arrays

Tags: php, json

[image: Quiero acceder al campo source que está dentro del array media, dentro de "data"]

Recogiendo por api el JSON tengo esto :

```
$resp =  $client->call("List", array("json_access" => json_encode($access), "json_media"=>json_encode($filters)));
$variable = file_get_contents($resp,true);
$decoded = json_decode($variable);
```

EDIT :

Al hacer var_code($decoded) me lanza esto:

```
Warning: file_get_contents({"status":"success","error":"0","data":{"media":[{"id":"1552057437978","name":"videoCorto.mp4","original_name":"videoCorto.mp4","file":"3423e47523e07d4a62731f6506c1f64b.mp4","src":"http:\/\/mediaexample.net\/ec\/3423e47523e07d4a62731f6506c1f64b.mp4","origin":"nfs","uploaded":"2019-03-08 15:03:57","modified":"2019-03-08 15:03:57","duration":"0","user":"1548956206177","size":1234124,"type":"video","extension":"mp4","hash":"3423e47523e07d4a62731f6506c1f64b","permissions":""},{"id":"1551972401965","name":"Eric","original_name":"Eric","file":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch? in C:\xampp\htdocs\Video1D3A\solicitudesok.php on line 90
```

Pero cuando hago un print_r($resp) sin hacer un file_get_content y solo con el json_decode me lanza todo el JSON con la estructura de la imagen de arriba, en donde quiero acceder a "src" y guardarlo en variable.

```
Array ( [status] => success [error] => 0 [data] => Array ( [media] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1552057437978 [name] => videoCorto.mp4 [original_name] => videoCorto.mp4 [file] => 3423e47523e07d4a62731f6506c1f64b.mp4 [src] => http://mediaexample.net/ec/3423e47523e07d4a62731f6506c1f64b.mp4 [origin] => nfs [uploaded] => 2019-03-08 15:03:57 [modified] => 2019-03-08 15:03:57 [duration] => 0 [user] => 1548956206177 [size] => 1234124 [type] => video [extension] => mp4 [hash] => 3423e47523e07d4a62731f6506c1f64b [permissions] => ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1551972401965 [name] => Eric [original_name] => Eric [file] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5fxiSNpO84 [src] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5fxiSNpO84 [origin] => youtube [uploaded] => 2019-03-07 15:26:41 [modified] => 2019-03-07 15:26:41 [duration] => 0 [user] => 1548956206177 [size] => -1 [type] => video [extension] => unknown [hash] => 1e760ac262891c619899e857948c9521 [permissions] => ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 1548958887843 [name] => 5-0 [original_name] => 5-0 [file] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oAgGH5wbMA [src] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oAgGH5wbMA [origin] => youtube [uploaded] => 2019-01-31 18:21:27 [modified] => 2019-01-31 18:21:27 [duration] => 0 [user] => 1548956206177 [size] => -1 [type] => video [extension] => unknown [hash] => 5039a2346f2f63e9754567b0d926552c [permissions] => ) ) ) )
```

Para luego ese source enviarlo a reproducir en un Video JS.

EDIT 2

Hice este foreach con tal de ir accediendo al src:

```
$resp =  $client->call("ListMedia", array("json_access" => json_encode($access), "json_media_filters"=>json_encode($filters)));
$decoded =json_decode($resp,true);
foreach($decoded["data"] as $clave => $valor) {
print "$clave => $valor\n";
}
```

Y me lanza lo siguiente:

> ```
> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Video1D3A\solicitudesok.php on line 94 media => Array
> ```

Un compañero ha escrito una formula pero no logro entenderlo bien aunque sé que se refiere a acceder al objecto, al array -> "campo que se quiera acceder". Pero como lo implementaria?

Gracias

Comment: debes poner un ejemplo minimo del json recibido de paso te recomindo que pases por [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agregar el resultado de hacer `var_export($decoded);`

Comment: Muchas gracias @Bryro , he añadido mas info, llevo viendo esta comunidad hace un tiempo pero es la primera vez que formulo una pregunta.

Comment: Gracias @Marcos, he añadido la info restante.

Comment: debes publicar el codigo no la imagen. ya se te habia explicado edita! y agrega texto no imagen!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. El hecho de que publiques capturas de pantalla en lugar del texto con el contenido del objeto dificulta que te ayudemos. Lo que es evidente es que en `$resp` ya tienes una cadena lista para ser convertida a JSON, por tanto, no necesitas usar `file_get_contents`. En cuanto a `src`, se encuentra dentro de un array de un objeto cuya clave es `media`, por lo que podrías acceder a ese valor con algo como: `$objeto->media[0]->src` es lo que se ve a simple vista. En la imagen es un poco confuso y difícil de analizar, convendría que pongas el texto con el contenido.

Comment: @Bryro lo siento nuevamente, vale está. Gracias

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias !! he editado el post y logro entender tu método que das pero no entiendo como implementarlo teniendo la variable $resp que tiene la cadena.

Comment: El dato que te interesa está en `media`, por tanto prueba algo así: `foreach($decoded["data"]["media"] as $row) { echo $row["src"].PHP_EOL;
}`

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano por tu interés en ayudarme, probé tu codigo y lo bueno es que no me lanza error jaja, pero lo malo es que no me muestra nada, pero sé que va por ahí, seguiré viendolo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siendo que `$resp` tiene aparentemente una cadena JSON válida, entonces, crea un objeto JSON a partir de dicha variable, y luego trabaja ese JSON para obtener los datos que quieres.

Yo particularmente, si trabajo con objetos JSON, evito la conversión a array, no es necesario, pueden ocurrir problemas de codificación y la sintaxis JSON es más clara.

Si se analiza bien la estructura del JSON, se puede ver que:

- los datos que te interesan están en la clave `media` del JSON
- lo que hay en esa clave es un array de objetos JSON
- la clave `media` se encuentra anidada dentro de `data`

Entonces puedes hacer esto simplemente:

```
# Creas un JSON desde $resp. NÓTESE que no uso TRUE, no me interesa un array
$json=json_decode($resp);
# Buscas el array de objetos JSON que hay en media, clave que está a su vez en data
$arrMedia=$json->data->media;
foreach ($arrMedia as $jsonMedia){
    # Como es un JSON, accedemos así $jsonMedia->src
    # Si interesa cualquier otro valor del objeto, se obtendría mediante la misma notación
    # por ejemplo, para obtener el nombre: $jsonMedia->name
    echo $jsonMedia->src.PHP_EOL;
}
```

He reproducido una muestra de tu cadena, y funciona, el código de más arriba me imprime algo como:

```
http://mediaexample.net/ec/3423e47523e07d4a62731f6506c1f64b.mp4
http://mediaexample.net/ec/ooooootrovalor.mp4
```

O sea, todos los valores de la clave `src` que hay en el array de objetos JSON dentro de `media`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias !! Eres muy amable ! Gracias nuevamente ! me sirvió !